# Find Commit Messages With Line Breaks

Tags: svn

Some people have used line breaks in their commit messages which is making parsing the logs a pain.
I want to identify the commit messages that contain multiple lines so that I can subsequently remove them.

If I do svn log --xml I can start parsing the msg tag but so far I have only managed to get a list of the messages.

```
svn log --xml --stop-on-copy http://myserver.com/branches|awk -F '[<>]' '/msg/{print $3}' |while read line;do echo $line|wc -l;done
```

The line count is always 1 because the while/read loop reads each line.

Even if I didn't have this line count problem, by this point I have lost the commit id.

How can I find out which commit messages have line breaks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that scripting is not always the answer!

TortoiseSVN has a Regular Expression option in the log viewer so you can just type `\n` to look for line breaks.
You can conveniently edit the log message from there too (assuming you have the correct hook in place.